# conditional probability - determining correct percentages

Tags: probability, statistics

so the problem I m having deals with conditional probability. I am given so much information and don't know what to do with what. Here is the problem:

"A study investigated whether men and women place more importance on a mate's ability to express his/her feelings or on a  mate's ability to make a good living. In the study, 55% of the participants were men, 71% of participants said that feelings were more important, and 35% of the participants were men that said feelings were more important. Suppose that an individual is randomly selected from the participants in this study. Let M be the event that the individual is male and F be the event that the individual said that feelings were more important."

I am asked to find $P(M' \cap F)$

I get confused on which percentages to use. For instance, 55% of all the participants were men, so that means 45% were women. 71% of the participants said feelings were more important so that means 29% said feelings were not important. Of the 71% that said feelings were important, 35% of them were men. So does that means the percentage of women that said feelings were important is 65%? Or would that be 36%? Since I am finding $P(M' \cap F)$, for M' would I use the 65% (or 36%) or would I use the 45% of the total population?

Thanks

Comment: So for $P(M' \cap F)$ would t be 65% then?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that

"35% of the participants were men that said feelings were more important"

means the same as

" Of the 71% that said feelings were important, 35% of them were men"

The original question does not contain any conditional probabilities.

I read the information provided as ...

$$ P(M)=0.55 \,\,\,P(F)= 0.71 \,\,\, P(M \cap F)=0.35 $$

So 
$$P(M' \cap F) = P(F)-P(M \cap F)=0.71-0.35=0.36$$

Answer (score 2):

It's sometimes easier to break this down into a table as follows:

[image]

As you can see the percentage that the are not male and consider feelings important is 36% i.e probability is 0.36.

Answer (score 0):

$P(M' and F)=P(F)*P(M' given F)$ so $P(F)=0.71$ and $P(M'givenF)= 0.36/0.71$

Thus,
$P(M' and F)=0.71*0.36/0.71=0.36$

I edited, initially had the wrong value for M'givenF.